# Using Sendgrid API to send emails

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I'm sending emails using the Sendgrid API, but every email that I send does not have the `Subjet`.

My code looks like this:

```
def send_notification(sendgrid_key, p_email):
    message = Mail(
        from_email=('my_email@mail.com'),
        to_emails=(p_email),
        subject='subject email',
    )
    message.template_id = 'XXXXXX'

    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(sendgrid_key)
        response = sg.send(message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Eventhought, I have set the `subjet`, I'm still receiving emails without subject. Moreover, I do not have any errors when my app run.

[image: I receive the email without subject]

Comment: Which version of the SendGrid python library are you using?

Comment: I have been using sendgrid 6.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

When you are using SendGrid's dynamic templates you actually set the subject in the template, not through the API. Take a look at this screenshot to see where you set the subject in the template editor.

[image]

If you want to set the subject dynamically too, you can add a template string in the subject and set that through dynamic template variables when you send the email. Check this article on [creating a dynamic email subject line with mustache templates](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260802535110-Create-a-Dynamic-Email-Subject-Line-with-Mustache-Templates) for more information.